# "Visible strap of the bra on shoulder"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary, word-usage

Is there any word for the strap of the bra that is visible on shoulder.?

Mostly it is addressed as strap which is obviously a common word not specific to bra or any inner-wear.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply called a *[bra strap](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bra-strap)*

In the US (and elsewhere), current fashion often allows bra straps to show.  In earlier eras, such a display might have been considered a *[peekaboo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peekaboo)* style

> offering only limited display or disclosure especially of a teasing sort

Now, almost *[anything goes](http://www.metrolyrics.com/anything-goes-lyrics-cole-porter.html)* (maybe even a glimpse of stocking).

Comment: Now I know fashion is becoming more and more bizarre, but I have to admit even these days I cannot imagine many people wear stockings on their shoulders!

Comment: I saw a youtube video where the hosts were wearing stockings on their arms and shoulders, printed with tatoo patterns.  Instant Tats!